# Efficiently managing a pool of HttpClients

Tags: java, http, httpclient, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x

Currently, I am trying to create an utility class which is to serve as the calling point of any HTTP request executed throughout the application. My implementation currently looks somewhat like this:

```
public class HttpHelper {

    private final static HttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    private final static CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(poolingConnManager).build();

    public static String GET(String endpoint, HashMap<String, String> headers) {
       /* httpClient.execute(...) */
    }
}
```

Thus, HTTP requests can be smoothly executed from anywhere in the application through:

`String result = HttpHelper.GET(URL, headers);`

Would this be an appropriate way of doing it? Is the pool of connections managed efficiently in such a class?

Comment: _Would this be an appropriate way of doing it?_ Static methods make unit tests unnecessarily cumbersome.  Does the project use any DI framework?

Comment: Yes, the project makes use of the Spring Boot ecosystem. Injecting the class above as a ```@Service``` (in Spring context) is not really the issue, but rather I am more concerned if I am instantiating the ```HttpClient``` and pool manager correctly.

Comment: Since using Spring, there's really no reason to make `poolingConnManager`, `httpClient`, and the method static. Spring will create a single instance by default that can be injected where needed.  But also, why not use `RestTemplate` or `WebClient`, instead of `httpCllient` directly?  If needed, the `RestTemplate` or `WebClient` can be configured.